# How to integrate sugarcrm on magento?

Tags: magento, sugarcrm

I need to integrate sugarcrm on my magento site.(using Wampserver2.2) where i can install **sugarcrm** ... Inside magento folder or inside the www directory?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Magento Extension 
[SugarCRM Bridge](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/sugarcrm-bridge.html)

This will help to connect between Magento and SugarCRM to an extend.

Comment: You can built your own module using Magento and SugarCRM APIs.

Answer (score 0):

SugarCRM and Magento are two different applications ; and should be installed as such.

Generally, if you are using Apache as your web-server, you will put them in two separate [**VirtualHosts**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/vhosts/) -- this way, each one will be independent, will have its own URL, and you will be be able to update each one without risking breaking the other one in the process.

Note that no matter how you deploy those two applications *(be it mixing both inside a single virtualhost, which is not a good idea, or using two distinct virtualhosts)*, they will still be two distinct, separate, applications, that don't share anything ; especially not their database.

What I mean, for example, is that the customers in Magento will not appear in SugarCRM ; same for the orders, or any other kind of data.